# Populate second dropdown based on selected objects in multi-select dropdown?

Tags: .net, knockout.js

Using Knockout v3.4.0 and ASP.NET MVC, I'd like to create a multi-select dropdown that populates another dropdown with the first dropdown's selected items.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/fo8eaesu/1/) is what I've come up with so far.. You'll see that there are a couple issues with this approach:

1. My .NET view model for selected medical conditions consists purely of IDs. However, I'm using the full model in Knockout to populate the second dropdown. Thus, the selected values are not being populated on initial page load. I could extend my .NET view model to include the full Medical Condition objects, rather than just IDs, but it wouldn't really make sense posting that information back to the server.. On submit, all I need to know is the list of IDs that are selected.
2. None of the values for the multi-select are populated (because I'm using the `selectedOptions` attribute to pass the full model and not specifying `optionsValue`. Thus, when submitting the form back to the server, all the selected items have values of 0.. which is obviously incorrect.

How can I accomplish this functionality using Knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you really want to use the id field as the value (particularly when it goes to the server), so you just need to do a little converting so you can get the whole object from the id.

It didn't look like the mapping was doing anything helpful, so I just used the raw data to keep things as simple as possible. Now your list of chosen IDs is denoted as such, and the chosen medical condition list is computed from it.

```
  self.availableMedicalConditions = rawConditionData;

  //my .NET view model has a list of IDs, not list of objects which are selected
  self.chosenMedicalConditionIds = ko.observableArray([53, 543, 954]);
  self.chosenMedicalConditions = ko.computed(function() {
    var result = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.chosenMedicalConditionIds(), function(id) {
      var conditions = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.availableMedicalConditions, function(condition) {
        return condition.MedicalConditionId === id;
      });
      if (conditions.length > 0) {
        result.push(conditions[0]);
      }
    });
    return result;
  });
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fo8eaesu/2/).